# Insert duplicate hash values into new hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>1, :name=>"Test1", :symbol=>"test", :attribute=>"test1", :eq_type=>"t1"},
 {:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>2, :name=>"Test2", :symbol=>"test2", :attribute=>"test2", :eq_type=>"t1"},
 {:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>1, :name=>"Test1", :symbol=>"test", :attribute=>"test1", :eq_type=>"t2"},
 {:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>2, :name=>"Test3", :symbol=>"test", :attribute=>"test1", :eq_type=>"t2"}]
```

I would like to create another array of hashes but it will be grouped on `:eq_type` with all relevant name values.

The desired output is:

```
[{:eq_type=>"t1" :name=>"Test1,Test2"},
 {:eq_type=>"t2" :name=>"Test1,Test3"}]
```

Comment: Obligatory: what have you tried so far?  Why doesn't your attempted solution work?

Comment: Look at Enumerable#group_by

Comment: Your "array of hashes" are not correct. Please make them something that Ruby will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.group_by { |h| h[:eq_type] }.map do |k, v|
  {eq_type: k, name: v.map { |h| h[:name] }.join(',') }
end
```

Where `arr` is:

```
[{:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>1, :name=>"Test1", :symbol=>"test", :attribute=>"test1", :eq_type=>"t1"},
 {:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>2, :name=>"Test2", :symbol=>"test2", :attribute=>"test2", :eq_type=>"t1"},
 {:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>1, :name=>"Test1", :symbol=>"test", :attribute=>"test1", :eq_type=>"t2"},
 {:type=>"Item", :ordinal=>2, :name=>"Test3", :symbol=>"test", :attribute=>"test1", :eq_type=>"t2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
arr = [{:name=>"Test1", :symbol=>"test",  :eq_type=>"t1"},
       {:name=>"Test2", :symbol=>"test2", :eq_type=>"t1"},
       {:name=>"Test1", :symbol=>"test",  :eq_type=>"t2"},
       {:name=>"Test3", :symbol=>"test",  :eq_type=>"t2"}]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| (h[g[:eq_type]] ||= []) << g[:name] }.
    map { |k,v| { eq_type: k, name: v.join(',') } }
  #=> [{:eq_type=>"t1", :name=>"Test1,Test2"},
  #    {:eq_type=>"t2", :name=>"Test1,Test3"}]
```